# Path finding algorithm to maximise points of interest along the route

Tags: graph-algorithms, shortest-path

I am trying to write an algorithm to find a path (not the shortest one) between a given start and end point.

An user will enter the start location, the end location and the available time to travel. For each edge of my graph I know the cost in time to traverse that edge and the gain in points of interest along that edge. I want to find the path witch maximises the gain in points of interest and falls within the given time.

Until now I only found references to A Star routing algorithm or optimisations to it witch only compute the shortest path.

Could you please give me some hints on what algorithm should I use or some references to solutions of similar problems? This algorithm is an important part of my Dissertation.

Thank you,
Radu-Stefan

Comment: Check this out: http://www.jucs.org/jucs_16_3/mobile_agent_routing_with/jucs_16_03_0372_0401_camponogara.pdf

Comment: This is called the Orienteering problem in the operations research/algorithms literature. It is NP-Hard (easy to prove this via a reduction from the Hamiltonianian Cycle Problem). Approximation algorithms are known in both undirected and directed graphs. A simple Google scholar search on orienteering will bring up several.

Comment: Setting the time to infinity would give you [the longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), so this problem is *strongly* NP-Hard.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri comment->answer please ? so the system doesn't keep bring this question back to life ?

Comment: I have used Bioinspired algo: [Ant Colony Optimization Routing Algorithm with Tabu Search](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2010/IMECS2010_pp2104-2107.pdf) with reference to your exact problem statement for [my conference paper](http://searchdl.org/index.php/conference/view/430)

Comment: @ChandraChekuri thank you for you comment. A simple Google scholar search really did the job. I found the following paper very useful: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~chekuri/papers/orienteering-journal.pdf